# JQuery UI Sortable: Tables with sets of rows?

Tags: jquery-ui, html-table

I have an HTML table (#view-page-table) with close to the following HTML:

```
<table id="view-page-table">
    <thead>
        <th>Header1</th>
        <th>Header2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Group 1</td><td>Group 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group 1</td><td>Group 1</td></tr>

        <tr><td>Group 2</td><td>Group 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group 2</td><td>Group 2</td></tr>

        <tr><td>Group 3</td><td>Group 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group 3</td><td>Group 4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My jQuery is simple right now:

```
function reOrder() {
    $("#view-page-table tbody").sortable({
        helper: function(e, ui) {
             ui.children().each(function() {
                 $(this).width($(this).width());
             });
             return ui;
        }
    }).disableSelection();
}
```

It seems to work fine (the helper function is to maintain cell width while moving). The only problem is, I need to move two `<tr>`'s at a time. In other words, the user needs to drag all of group one, two, or three without being able to drag just one row. I tried to add a div in the table but I guess that's a no-no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have solution, but not optimum.
try to make tabel inside

```
<tbody>
        <tr><td>Group 1</td><td>Group 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group 1</td><td>Group 1</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
        <tr><td>Group 2</td><td>Group 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group 2</td><td>Group 2</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
        <tr><td>Group 3</td><td>Group 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Group 3</td><td>Group 4</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

And replace your script with this one

```
function reOrder() {
    $("#view-page-table").sortable({
        helper: function(e, ui) {
             ui.children().each(function() {
                 $(this).width($(this).width());
             });
             return ui;
        },
        handle: "tbody"
    }).disableSelection();
}
```

Best of Luck

Comment: The above code didn't work for me, I had to replace `handle: "tobdy"` by `items: "tbody"`. Otherwise, very nice solution!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Using something similar, I achieved technically correct results, but with extreme formatting issues. I eventually abandoned my effort and relooked at how I approached the issue altogether. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the related rows in their own tbody tag. You can use multiple tbody tags in a single table. This is an ideal use case.

Comment: Awesome answer!  Had no idea that was possible!

Answer (score 1):

The Ahmed Assaf solution need to be modified as below

HTML Code

```
<table id="sort" border="1" width="500">  
    <thead>  
    <tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th></tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody class="red">
            <tr><td>Group 1</td><td>Group 1</td><td>Group 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Group 1</td><td>Group 1</td><td>Group 1</td></tr>
    </tbody>                                    
    <tbody>                                     
            <tr><td>Group 2</td><td>Group 2</td><td>Group 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Group 2</td><td colspan="2">Group 2 and Group 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>                                    
    <tbody class="blue">                                     
            <tr><td>Group 3</td><td>Group 3</td><td>Group 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Group 3</td><td>Group 4</td><td>Group 4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script Code

```
// Return a helper with preserved width of cells  
var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {  
  ui.children().children().each(function() { 
    $(this).width($(this).width()); 
  });  
  return ui;  
};

$("#sort").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper,
        items: "tbody"
    }).disableSelection();
```

In the fixHelper function the code line

```
ui.children().each(function()
```

need to be replace with

```
ui.children().children().each(function()
```

to catch the TD width value.

And the line

```
handle: "tbody"
```

need to be replace with

```
items: "tbody"
```

has indicated by **rlanvin** in his comment

[Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NexusFred/155zqt5m/)

Best Regard
NexusFred

Comment: which jquery-ui version is required to set helper with parameter? for me param 'ui' is giving error

Comment: Sorry for the delay. In this demo I use the JQuery UI 1.11.4.